# How to speed up VS.NET 2015 solution loading and pasting into ASPX source view?

Tags: visual-studio

I just installed Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 Version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL hoping for a performance improvement over 2013.  When I load a very large ASP.NET web forms solution, I have to wait over 30 seconds. After it is loaded, when I try to paste text into the source view of an ASPX page, I am intermittantly enduring a 15+ second wait.  A popup tells me that VS.NET is busy performing background tasks.

I'm running Windows 7 Pro SP1 x64 on a recently purchased Dell Precision workstation with 16GB RAM and an Intel Xeon E3-1240 v3 @ 3.40GHz.  My C: drive is on a SamSung SSD.  Here is what I would like to know:

What can I do to make VS.NET 2015 perform faster?

Answer (score 2):

I found that VS.NET was I/O bound because when I disabled Microsoft Security Essentials entirely the performance was acceptable.  There is an option in MS Security to exclude certain processes from security scans.  After I added ~/Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe to MS Security Essentials' list of excluded processes, it ran acceptably fast.

Comment: And after disabling Fusion logging, I no longer had to disable MS Security Essentials to get decent performance.  I forgot that I enabled it long ago.  The log files that had accumulated were in the gigabytes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ReSharper then turning it off makes performance considerably faster. Similarly Node.js Tools for Visual Studio can slow down your IDE.

Comment: I have neither ReSharper nor node.js tools installed.